# Принцип работы с пулом IP адресов на почтовом сервере

Tags: smtp

Как можно использоваться пул IP-адресов для работы с почтовым сервером рассылки (для реальных подписчиков)?

По какому принципу работают UniSender или MailChimp? Может быть, где-то есть примеры.

Answer (score 2):

вероятно, в первую очередь вас интересуют **отправка** писем.

из вопроса не совсем ясно, как эти ip-адреса распределены между машинами, поэтому изложу вкратце свои соображения по всем трём вариантам:

1. несколько серверов, по одному ip-адресу на сервер.

   насколько я понимаю, конфигурация ничем не отличается от одиночного сервера, кроме количества пунктов в spf-записи.

   распределение нагрузки осуществляет п.о., отсылающее письма.
2. один сервер и несколько ip-адресов.

   распределение нагрузки — средствами самого smtp-сервера. первые попавшиеся статьи:

   1. про [exim](http://reqad.com/how-to-send-mail-from-multiple-ips-in-exim.html).
   2. про [postfix](http://marinovl.blogspot.ru/2012/09/postfix-how-to-balance-outgoing-emails.html).
3. несколько серверов, по нескольку ip-адресов на сервер.

   просто комбинация из первого и второго пунктов: распределение нагрузки и средствами п.о., отсылающего письма, и средствами самих smtp-серверов.